# Property between trace class and Hilbert-Schmidt

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the following condition on a bounded operator $T$ on a Hilbert space:

$\ \ \ \ \ $(A) there exists an orthonormal basis $(e_j)$ with $\sum_j\parallel Te_j\parallel<\infty$.

We have the implications

$\ \ \ \ \ $(trace class) $\ \Rightarrow\ $ (A) $\ \Rightarrow\ $ (Hilbert-Schmidt)

But what about the converse directions? Are they both false or is one of them true?

Comment: A diagonal operator shows that (A) is strictly stronger than Hilbert-Schmidt.

Comment: That requires to show that the sum is infinite for every ONB. How do you show that?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right.  "exists an" is the key phrase which I overlooked!

Comment: Isn't (A) equivalent to (trace class)? Indeed, if $y_j=T e_j$ satisfies $\sum_j \|y_j\| <\infty$, then $T= \sum_j \langle \cdot,e_j\rangle y_j$ is a norm-converging series of rank $1$ operators.

Comment: Trace class is not closed under norm convergence, though.

Comment: But for rank $1$ operators, trace norm and operator norm are equal, so the sum is convergent for the trace norm.

Comment: I also think that (A) implies (trace class). Indeed, assuming (A), we have that $\sum_j\langle|T|e_j,e_j\rangle\leq\sum_j\||T|e_j\|=\sum_j\|Te_j\|<\infty$, so $T$ is trace class.

Comment: @GH from MO: Why does that imply trace class? It would, if you had this for every ONB, but you have it only for one.

Comment: @Corbennick: The left hand side in my inequality is independent of the ONB. By definition, $T$ is trace class if and only if $\sum_j\langle|T|e_j,e_j\rangle$ is finite for some (hence for every) ONB $\{e_j\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Condition (A) is equivalent to $T$ being trace class. I will use the usual notation $|T|:=(T^\ast T)^{1/2}$.

**1.** Assume that condition (A) holds. Then 
$$\sum_j\langle|T|e_j,e_j\rangle\leq\sum_j\||T|e_j\|=\sum_j\|Te_j\|<\infty.$$
The left hand side is finite, hence $T$ is trace class by definition.

**2.** Assume that $T$ is trace class. Let $(e_j)$ be an orthonormal eigenbasis of $|T|$. Then
$$\sum_j\|Te_j\|=\sum_j\||T|e_j\|=\sum_j\langle|T|e_j,e_j\rangle<\infty.$$
The left hand side is finite, hence condition (A) holds.

Note that this answers the question completely, since trace class is a strictly stronger property than Hilbert-Schmidt.